# GitHub Token - Restrict Access

Tags: git, github, github-api, github-api-v3

I am using GitHub token as the credential for others people.
Can make the token only allows the user to `clone` and `pull`, but NOT `push` or `delete`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GitHub tokens do not provide access to a repository, it is mainly to provide authentication of the user. 
Clone or Pull or push are mainly GitHub repository functions and you can manage specific access using Setting --> Contributors for the repository. Select the "Read" option in the contributors option of Repository Settings.

Answer (score 1):

GitHub tokens can now ([Oct. 2022](https://github.blog/changelog/2022-10-18-introducing-fine-grained-personal-access-tokens/)) provide access to a repository, if you set [GitHub App permissions](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/overview/permissions-required-for-github-apps#git)

That way, even a contributor might not have all write access (ie might not trigger a GitHub action, change protection, patch a commit, [push a commit](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/overview/permissions-required-for-github-apps#git-1), ...

You now can define a much more granular access through those new fine-grained personal access token.