# create access token only for specific repo in github

Tags: github, github-actions, access-token, github-api

**I am using GitHub Actions.
To access the self-hosted runners API needed admin:org scope aceess token I'm creating a personal access token with admin:org scope
But with this token we can access all git repos that is avalable in my organazaion. To avaoid misused please help me to create admin token for specific repo with that i can able to use github runners api and all features of github actions.**

**Access tokens require admin:org scope**

```
admin:org    Full control of orgs and teams, read and write org projects
write:org    Read and write org and team membership, read and write org projects
read:org     Read org and team membership, read org projects
manage_runners:org   Manage org runners and runner groups
```

[image]

Comment: did you find out how to do it?

Comment: See [GitHub Token - Restrict Access](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74117912/6309) or [GitHub OAuth2 Token: How to restrict access to read a single private repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74117850/6309)

Answer (score 0):

Github introduced [Fine-Grained Personal Access Tokens in Oct 2022](https://github.blog/2022-10-18-introducing-fine-grained-personal-access-tokens-for-github/).

This feature allows you to set the Repository Access to "Only Select Repositories" to restrict it to a specific repo(s).

Documentation: https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/managing-your-personal-access-tokens

[image: Screenshot of Repository Access]

Comment: The targetted repo does not appear on the options.